# Getting a nullpointer exception on getApiClient

Tags: android

```
 public void doSignUp(OnAddUpdateListener<SignUpValidationError> listListener, SignUpRequest request) {
    mListener = listListener;
    LeafApiClient apiClient = LeafApplication.getInstance().getApiClient();
    LeafService service = apiClient.getService(LeafService.class);
    final Call<SignUpResponse> model = service.signup(request);
    ResponseWrapper<SignUpResponse> wrapper = new ResponseWrapper<>(model);
```

I'm getting a error on apiClient as : Cant invoke getApiClient() on a null object reference

```
 private LeafApiClient apiClient;
private static LeafApplication sInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    sInstance = this;


 public static LeafApplication getInstance(){
    return sInstance;
}

public synchronized LeafApiClient getApiClient(){
    if (apiClient == null){
        apiClient = LeafApiClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return apiClient;
}
```

This is the code from where i invoke the method getApiClient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Also, have you declared your Application in the manifest?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to android programming..... Can u please tell me what should i declare in the manifest????

Comment: It's in the official guide https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

You can provide your own implementation by creating a subclass and specifying the fully-qualified name of this subclass as the "android:name" attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml's <application> tag.

Comment: I did that too... but I'm still getting the same error..... When i debug my code only getApiClient() method is not executing!!!

Comment: Can you put a break point on `onCreate()` inside your Application. Is it getting called?

Comment: onCreate is getting called and i also included the name attribute in manifest file..... but the debugging stops after  LeafApiClient apiClient = LeafApplication.getInstance().getApiClient();

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I included the name attribute and rebuild the project... It works fine now!!!!

Comment: Well done! Glad the comnent helped

Comment: Ya it helped for sure!!!! Thank you!!!